# How to mount large drive

Tags: filesystems, storage

I have a computer with a 250 or so SSD and a new 10 TB drive. How should I mount the new drive? I have seen some examples on the web where the person just mounts it to a randomly named root path like `/store`. The problem I see with this is that all the usual directories like /usr and /var are on the SSD, so they could run out of space. Also, having a lot of space in some random place like "/store" seems illogical. Normally, when I store data I put it in my home directory.

Is there a logical way to mount the new drive so that I will be unlikely to run out of space in any of my directories?

Answer (score 3):

To keep it flexible, you might consider a bind mounting scheme, where you mount the whole disk somewhere (`/store` is fine), and then "bind mount" top level directories of the big disk to directories inside your home area. For example,

```
# mount /dev/sdb /store
# mount -o bind /store/dir1 /home/Tyler/Documents
# mount -o bind /store/dir2 /Home/Tyler/Downloads
```

In that way you can let the huge space of 10Tb be available at many of your directories without committing upfront on which should use the most of the space.

Just an idea.